# Negation of a statement without using (symbol ¬)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> Write the negation of the following statement (without using the symbol $¬$ ):
>
> $\mathrm P ~=~ (∃x ∈ \Bbb R)\Big(\big((∃y ∈ \Bbb R)(x = (1 − y)^2)\big) ∧ \big((∃z ∈ \Bbb R)(x = −z^2)\big)\Big)$
>
> Which statement is true, $\rm P$ or $\rm ¬P$ ?

P.S.... i'm kinda confused as to not being able to use the $¬$ symbol for negating the statement.   So, how would I be able to do it?

Comment: I'm sure you're permitted to use $\ne$. And of course you should use $\neg$ while you're figuring out the final $\neg$-free form.

Comment: Yes.  Negate the statement $P$ and then, by using Dual Quantifier and deMorgan's Rules, obtain an equivalent form that does not rely in the $\neg$ symbol.

Answer (score 3):

What you are supposed to do, is the following: Consider $\neg P$ and then iteratively transform this into an equivalent sentence $Q$ in which the symbols $\neg$ doesn't appear. I will show you how to begin:

(I'm assuming that your $R$ is supposed to be $\mathbb R$ - the set of all reals.)
$$
\begin{align}
&\neg \left( \exists x \in \mathbb R \exists y \in \mathbb R \colon x = (1-y)^2 \wedge \exists z \in \mathbb R \colon x = -z^2 \right) \\
\Leftrightarrow &\neg \left( \exists x \in \mathbb R \exists y \in \mathbb R \colon x = (1-y)^2 \right) \vee \neg \left( \exists z \in \mathbb R \colon x = -z^2 \right) \\
\Leftrightarrow &\forall x \in \mathbb R \neg \left( \exists y \in \mathbb R \colon x = (1-y)^2 \right) \vee \forall z \in \mathbb R \colon x \neq -z^2 \\
&\ldots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Does that mean the final answer would be:                                                   P ≠ ((∀x∈R)(((∀y∈R)(x≠(1-y)^2))∨((∀z∈R)(x≠-z^2)))

Comment: It should read $\neg P \equiv \forall x \in \mathbb R \forall y \in \mathbb R \colon x \neq (1-y)^2 \vee \forall z \in \mathbb R \colon x \neq -z^2$, but yes. That's right. Now you have to find out whether $P$ or $\neg P$ is true.